# can I have a typescript class constructor that has input parameter guide?

Tags: typescript

Sorry I am new in Javascript and Typescript.

in Swift using Xcode IDE, if I make a class, then If I make an instance, it will have its parameter name as a guide in the constructor, like the image below, so I will not put the wrong value in the constructor

[image]

but if I use Typescript and do the same thing, I will not have that parameter guide like this

[image]

it is easy if the class only has 2 properties like that, but if it has more than 10 properties then it will be confusing, I often put the wrong argument

is there a way to make something like that? VS Code extension or whatever it is. please help :)

```
class User {
    name: string
    age: number
    
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const someone = new User("John Doe", 12);
```

Comment: Use TSLint Extension in VS Code along with the tslint.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, the VS Code Extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liamhammett.inline-parameters